# Can't start symfony server

Tags: symfony

I'm new to symfony and while following the video tutorial, I ran into the problem. The guy in the video started his server without any problems, but for me, while trying to run `php bin/console server:start` I get a huge error message. Please bear with me as Im the begginer and thank you for all the help.

[image: Error I get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) library. As the first comment on [Installing/Configuring](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php) notices, on some linux-distributions this library is not included in the minimal PHP package.

> Certain Linux distributions do not have this extension included in the
>   minimum PHP package. It can usually be found in one of the "optional"
>   php-* packages.
>
> For CentOS, you will need to run "yum install php-xml", which provides
>   this extension.

As this looks like ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install php-xml` should do the job.